# Get every Y value from every line based on a X value

Tags: wpf, line, oxyplot

Using `OxyPlot` library, I have a `LineSeries` with a max count of 8. Given a `X` value (got from a left mouse click), how can I get (and show it in the legend) the corresponding `Y` value for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the point value using the MouseDown method which you attach to your line series found [here](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Examples/MouseEventExamples.cs) in the MouseDownEventHitTestResult method

```
var s1 = new LineSeries();
s1.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        model.Subtitle = "Y value of nearest point in LineSeries: " +
            Math.Round(e.HitTestResult.NearestHitPoint.Y);
        model.InvalidatePlot(false);
    };
```

There doesn't appear to be any way to change much of whats in the legend area as that's just a reflection of the graph titles. You could display it to the subtitle as in the example or draw an annotation on the screen.

They have a whole bunch of examples you can look through for ideas [here](http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/)